# jquery validation rules and a weird IE7 error

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-7

I have the following validation:

```
 phone1: {
      required: {
       depends: "#pri_noPhone:not(:checked)"
      },
       number: true,
       minlength:3,
},
```

If a checkbox is checked (yes, contact me via phone) then go validate the phone1, phone2 and phone3.

In FF and Firebug, there are no errors. However, IE7 throws an error saying:

a runtime error has occurred.
error: expected identifier, string or number

and it points to the rules at phone1. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

i had to remove the comma after :  minlength:3,

Comment: I encountered the same problem in ie6. After removing the comma, everything works right now. For the detailed info, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript maybe helpful.