# Are trailing commas in arrays and objects part of the spec?

Tags: javascript

Are trailing commas standard in JavaScript, or do most browsers like Chrome and Firefox just tolerate them?

I thought they were standard, but IE8 puked after encountering one—of course IE not supporting something hardly means it’s not standard.

Here’s an example of what I mean (after the last element of the books array):

```
var viewModel = {
    books: ko.observableArray([
        { title: "..", display: function() { return ".."; } },
        { title: "..", display: function() { return ".."; } },
        { title: "..", display: function() { return ".."; } }, // <--right there
    ]),
    currentTemplate: ko.observable("bookTemplate1"),
    displayTemplate: function() { return viewModel.currentTemplate(); }
};
```

Comment: Found this the other day.  Being a C# programmer I was so used to them being allowed...

Comment: I dealt with this a few weeks ago.  Imagine trying to find this in IE7 without any of the newer debugging tools...

Comment: It made me happy when I discovered languages like JS, Ruby, C# support this—makes copy pasting test data easy...it made me angry when I realized IE sucks in even this...

Comment: I wonder if significant whitespace instead of commas (kind of like CoffeeScript) would cause any syntactic ambiguity?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Specs: [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) and [ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

---

[Section 11.1.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5) in the ECMAScript 5 specification:

```
ObjectLiteral :
    { }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList , }
```

So yes, it is part of the specification.

**Update:** Apparently this is new in ES5. In ES3 (page 41), the definition was just:

```
ObjectLiteral :
    { }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList }
```

---

For arrays literals ([Section 11.1.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.4)) it is even more interesting (**Update:** this already existed in ES3):

```
ArrayLiteral :
    [ Elisionopt ]
    [ ElementList ]
    [ ElementList , Elision_opt ]
```

(where `Elision_opt` is Elision<sub>opt</sub>, meaning the Elision is optional)

`Elision` is defined as

```
Elision :
    ,
    Elision ,
```

So, an array literal like

```
var arr = [1,2,,,,];
```

is perfectly legal. This creates an array with two elements but sets the array length to `2 + 3 = 5`.

Don't expect too much from IE (before IE9)...

Comment: As I asked EndoPhage, do you happen to know whether this was standard in ES3 as well?  I can't seem to find the spec for it

Comment: It's here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: Apparently, the trailing comma in object literals was not in the ES3 spec. But the definition for arrays is the same.

Comment: Well it was array elements that I ran into this with, so I guess there's no excuse for MS no matter how you cut it.  Thanks again

Comment: IIRC IE 8 will parse the array but place a null value in the array rather than ignoring it. IE7 and below would fail to parse.

Answer (score 95):

Just a quick reminder/warning that this is one of the areas in which the [JavaScript/ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) and [JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) differ; trailing commas are *valid* in JS but *not valid* in JSON.

Comment: But then again, if superset is in for a "Change Of Heart" , "Could you (still) be loved" if you just for once adjusted?

Answer (score 54):

What is even funnier, IE7 gives

```
[1,].length  --> 2
```

while Firefox and Chrome

```
[1,].length  --> 1
```

Comment: But `[1,,].length` gives `2`. **Sense**: browsers make none.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, the spec says that a (note: singular) trailing comma does not add to the length of an array. Chrome and Firefox have implemented ES5 correctly.

Comment: When there are 2 (plural) trailing commas, only one adds to the length of the array, so it seems more accurate to say that the final trailing comma is ignored than to say a single trailing comma is ignored.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer There is an exception to the trailing comma rule: `[,].length` gives `1`.

Comment: @ElijasDapšauskas that's not really an exception. The singular trailing comma doesn't add anything to the length but for it to exist there needs to be something to the left of it so `[,]` is equivalent to `[undefined,]` and `[undefined].length === 1`. Perhaps the wording of my comment leaves this case ambiguous but the specification does not.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the specification for javascript (aka ECMA Script) [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).  You can find the relevant definition for arrays on page 63 and as Felix noted, the object definition a couple of pages later on page 65.

While this specification says it is fine to have a trailing `,` I don't know if that would be true looking back a few versions.  As you've noted IE8- will crap itself if you leave a trailing comma but Chrome and FF handle it fine.

Comment: Off the top of your head, was this part of the ES3 standard?  I can't seem to find the ES3 spec

Comment: @Adam I've been trying to find it...  Given the release dates (ES3 was published in 1999, ES4 was abandoned and ES5 was only published in 2009), it would make sense that it was in the ES3 standard. Or it could just be that MS screwed up one more thing.

Comment: Looks like MS screwed up one more thing given Felix's answer.  Thanks again for yours

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this down.

> Are trailing commas standard in JavaScript?

Yes. As of the ECMAScript 5 specification (also part of the Google and Airbnb style guide)

> Do most browsers like Chrome and Firefox just tolerate them?

This is an ECMAScript 5 support question.

Transpilers like Babel will remove the additional trailing comma in the transpiled code which means you don’t have to worry about the trailing comma problem in legacy browsers.

So that means:

```
var heroes = [
  'Batman',
  'Superman',
];
// heroes.length === 2 (not 3)
```

So chances are if you're using anything ES5 and up you don't need to worry about it.

> I thought they were standard, but IE8 puked after encountering one—of course IE not supporting something hardly means it’s not standard.

Again, that's an ECMAScript 5 support question. IE8 doesn't support ECMAScript 5 (only IE9 and up)

I would highly recommend taking a look Airbnb's ES5 deprecated Documentation
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/es5-deprecated/es5/README.md#commas

I would also recommend the Mozilla's Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome 52 :

```
[1,].length --> 1
[1,2,].length --> 2
[].length --> 0 
[,].length --> 1    <<<<=== OUHHHHH !!!!
```

I just don't like trailing commas. People usually use them in Open Source projects for avoiding to erase the line written by another commiter. See the same question in Python : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11597911/968988

Comment: Why 'OUHHHHH'? What else did you expect there if not 1? You clearly 'have an element' before that comma, just like [1,] (which is length: 1).

Comment: Why 'OUHHHHH'? because I don't expect anything from a code that I don't understand without reading the RFC. And yes, it works just like `[1,]` : there is clearly something before the comma. But in `[,]` there is as much before and after the comma. So because I don't understand `[,]` alone, I dont think using `[1,]` is good idea.