# Object doesn't support this property or method in ieTester IE8 or below error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ietester

I have a 2 small script in the footer of my page, that produce a script error in IE8.  IEtester says that this script error is created from the document ready (but i believe it's just cuz it's the start).  I used jQuery so that it was cross browser compatible. :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //flexslider
   $(".flexslider").flexslider({
   animation : "slide",
    slideshow : true,
   animationDuration: "750",
   slideshowSpeed: 5000,
   pauseOnAction: true, 

  }); 

  //text slider overer
    $("#videos li").on({

  mouseenter: function() {
     $(this).animate({"padding-left": "50px"}, "normal");
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
       $(this).stop(true).animate({"padding-left": "0px"}, "slow");

  }});
  });
```

[image]
Does anyone know how to correct this script error?  If so, could you explain why this error is created in the first place?

first script html page:  http://designobvio.us/fonts/
Second script html page: http://designobvio.us/fonts/middle.php

Comment: What property or method does the error tell you is not supported? Any how about posting the script that's giving you the trouble?

Comment: Can you post the exact error into your question?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity the script is basically just being ignored

Comment: @MichelAyres code has been updated above

Comment: Have you done basic troubleshooting? Remove parts of the code until you figure out which one is causing the error. Look for more information in IE8's developer tools.

Comment: it starts at the document ready line.  I've removed each script one by one both create this error

Comment: So if you have `$(document).ready`, but nothing inside the function, it still does it?

Comment: lol document ready is giving the error now http://vvcap.net/db/CbjNHlDD0QnlUn_6B0_2.htp

Comment: What happens if you do `alert($)` before the `$(document).ready()`? Or use `console.log()` instead of `alert` if you have the dev tools going.

Comment: in ie it ignores it. i'll update code with alert

Comment: And removing the `$(document).ready` code entirely makes the error disappear?

Comment: that is correct cliff.  I just tested that.

Comment: I'll fire up IE8 in VMWare. It'll take me a few.

Comment: is there anything I should do to the live code to support you?

Comment: Yes, fix it before I have to get my hands dirty in IE8. ;-) Aside from that, not really, but thanks.

Comment: Oh, get rid of the trailing comma. That issue will come up eventually. Also, the first error I get is from the `ggs.js` script stating `"domReady" is undefined`. Can you remove that script?

Comment: got it removing sorry for the delay.!

Comment: that was it ggs was creating the script error thank you so much

Comment: Looks like that fixed it? ...you're welcome. Remember to keep the dev tools open `Tools > Developer Tools`, and keep an eye on the console. :)

Comment: Worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one issue that's sure to trip up IE8:

```
$(".flexslider").flexslider({
   animation : "slide",
    slideshow : true,
   animationDuration: "750",
   slideshowSpeed: 5000,
   pauseOnAction: true, // <-- Trailing comma
});
```

IE8 and lower hate trailing commas.

Comment: i'll update the code.  I'm sure that trailing comma was no good either

Comment: I have same issue in IE8 for the code var control = $('<object />',{classid: "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000",width: "100%",height: "100%",name: player.settings.name,codebase:"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab",html: html}); 
Coul't you suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the , from this line: pauseOnAction: true,

IE doesn't support commas on the end of the last line in an array or object.