# Uploadify browser compatibility issue

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin for allowing users to upload files to my website. The script works fine in chrome but does not work in ie and firefox

```
  $(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
     'checkExisting' : 'check-exists.php',
    'buttonText' : 'Select project',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '163840KB',
     'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.zip; *.rar',
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
         $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
        },
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    },

    });
```

any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has a trailing comma (the final one) which probably won't work in some versions of IE ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)).

Also, your brackets are not all closed. Try changing `});` to `}) });`