# Should comma be placed after each propery or array item in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Should we write

```
var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ];
var b = { '1', '2', '3', };
```

or

```
var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
var b = { '1', '2', '3' };
```

What is the most correct way?

I've noticed that old versions of IE raise error if there is comma expecting there would be a another array item (or property) after comma.

Comment: *related*: [Trailing commas in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7246618/218196).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've noticed that old versions of IE raise error if there is comma

That is reason enough to *not put a comma after the last element*! However, it *is* [valid to do so](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4).

Note however that your 2nd example...

```
var b = { '1', '2', '3', };
```

...will throw a syntax error. I'm guessing you intended to make it an object literal, but just made a mistake when writing the question:

```
var b = { x: '1', y: '2', z: '3', }; //Object literal, no syntax error :)
```

Comment: +1. However it is not a valid JSON - another reason to avoid it.

Comment: @freakish: What does JSON have to do with it? JSON notation also requires double quotes, but that just doesn't seem relevant when using object literal notation.

Comment: @user1689607 - Nothing really, but since JSON is just a very small, strict subset of JavaScript, it's worth a mention. However, it's probably worth noting that an array/object literal with trailing comma *will* still stringify to valid JSON.

Comment: @user1689607 Double quotes is a good practice as well. It is unlikely that OP is going to write his own JSON serializer/deserializer, but since JSON is extremely popular nowadays ( and it is directly related to JavaScript ) it is just worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

Both are *correct* according to the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Although this has nothing to do with JavaScript, FWIW, the trailing comma is [not allowed in JSON](http://json.org).

Answer (score 1):

I just laugh at this situation :)

```
// Firefox and Chrome 
["a", "b",].length // 2

// ie7
["a", "b",].length // 3 :)
```

Comment: This makes me sad. Direct contravention of the ES5 spec: "If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array." I'd expect it in IE < 9, but not really IE9 itself. However, worth noting that `["a", "b",,].length === 3` in correct implementations.

Comment: Oh, I just tried it. IE9 returns `2`, so it's not so bad. In IE8 and below you can just always expect things like that.

Comment: yes sample [11.1.4 Array Initialiser] --> http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @JamesAllardice  sorry ie9 change ie7 ok?

Comment: I'm not sure if IE8 does it or not as I don't have it to hand to test.  I didn't downvote by the way.

Comment: ie7 commas in a funny way :) length

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way is without a trailing comma as that implies something is to follow.