# jQuery Tagit! Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

I am using the jQuery tagit! library to create a user "Skills" input form. I figured this would be an extremely quick and simple setup like most jQuery libraries, however I am having a tremendous amount of trouble with this one. I tried following the source code on the example below, but I cannot get it to work even with the direct source code.

I am using the script found here: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

Here is the javascript that is initializing the tag-it library in the header:

```
$(function() {
    $('#skills').tagit({     
        singleField: true,
    });
});
```

And here is the `<ul>` element that is supposed to turn into an input field when the tag-it.js library is called:

```
<ul id="skills"></ul>
```

I am including all these files to get this to work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/tag-it.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tag-it.js"></script>
```

**All the files are being called correctly and I am not receiving any errors. There is NO input form where the `<ul>` tags are unless I create one manually**

Does anyone have a clue as to why this isn't working? Do I need to manually add an input field and assign a specific ID or class to it?

**EDIT:** This has been solved. The code posted is all 100% correct, I had an error in the jquery selector before tag-it initialization.

Comment: Runs fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RgKuc/

Comment: It does, you are correct. But I am still experiencing this issue on my page... could my cache have anything to do with it?

Comment: Without seeing the page it is hard to tell. Is your selector running? `$(function() { console.log($('#skills'));
    $('#skills').tagit({ ...`

Comment: No the selector was not running. There was an error in the selector before, which was preventing the script from executing further than the error. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem for me, my template had a script linking to a local jquery. So when i copy the jqueryui and jquery link from tagit, it overlaps. Geting rid of the local jquery did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with that comma

you have put

```
singleField: true,
```

but it has to be

```
singleField: true
```

If you have two options like

```
tagSource: availableTags,
singleField: true
```

then only the first option will have the comma
 the second or the last option (in case there are more than 2 options) will not have a comma

Comment: The trailing comma is perfectly fine in javascript, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript