# Flagging comma at last element of array as an error for JavaScript/Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have a Javascript project that must be compatible with older versions of IE, and I am using Eclipse Juno as my IDE.

Older versions of IE cannot handle a comma after the last element of an array, even though this is correct ECMAScript:

```
[a,b,c,]
```

Unfortunately, though this is correct syntax, it breaks my application only for IE, and only in production (where backwards compatibility is forced), and in a way that is very hard to debug (it does not fail anywhere near the line that is wrong).

Is there a way to set Eclipse to flag this as an error with the syntax validator?  I did not see this as an option under Preferences -> JavaScript -> Validator -> Errors/Warnings

Comment: Note: this is valid as of ES5. IE<8 do not support any ES5 features (in case you're wondering the reason, here's throughout [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7246662/1331430)).

Comment: Is there some good reason to have a trailing comma in an array? If you want to include undefined there, include the keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would warmly recommend installing [**jshint for eclipse**](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/install.html) which would analyze your code, and provide insightful reports about your code (including the problem you reported)

If you're not sure, just give [jshint a try](http://www.jshint.com/). Paste your code, press lint, and get the results.

**Example**

For the code:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,];
```

You get:

```
Line 1: var arr = [1,2,3,];

Extra comma. (it breaks older versions of IE)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Unfortunately it's also flagging a lot of errors for mixed spaces and tabs.  It looks like I should be able to tell JSHint to ignore this by setting "smarttabs: true" in the JSHint options, but this does not seem to make any difference...

Comment: **Or** you could be consistent about indentation. It only takes you once to (auto)-format it, and then just follow the standards. Jokes aside: I don't know about this bug.