# Kendo template fails to render properly in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI template that generates dynamic HTML similar to a data repeater.

- Because the Kendo template engine supports JavaScript I am using a "for, each" loop within the template itself.
- The output looks fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and above but it is broken in IE8.
- You can view the snippet reproducing the issue here: http://jsbin.com/ajazuw/6.
- I cannot see any JavaScript error when the content is rendered in IE 8 so I am assuming this might be caused by an IE8 specific issue in Kendo UI.

**UPDATE:**
The issue was caused by an extra quote in my template. See here:http://jsbin.com/ajazuw/11 for an updated working version of my template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to the trailing commas - IE chokes on them (see this topic for more details - [Are trailing commas in arrays and objects part of the spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)).

Try this - http://jsbin.com/iyiqib/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The problem still persists in IE8 if I remove the trailing commas(I updated my original jsbin link to a version that does not have any trailing commas)

Comment: I tested it in IE 10 with IE 8 mode, and it worked for me. I am not sure what goes wrong in the genuine one - you can test if $("#template").html() returns the correct value.

Comment: Upon closer look, it seems like the template features some extra quotes. Check them too.

Comment: omg, looking for hours cause template does not render. Result was an "</div>"  to much in my template! grr