# Why leave a trailing comma after a key value pair in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I was looking at gruntjs and I looked at some JSON examples used to configure Grunt tasks.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    foo: {
      // concat task "foo" target options and files go here.
    },
    bar: {
      // concat task "bar" target options and files go here.
    },
  },
  uglify: {
    bar: {
      // uglify task "bar" target options and files go here.
    },
  },
});
```

As you can see, there is an 'extra' comma after each of the bar properties. I tried this notation in Chrome and it is valid. Although it is valid, I wouldn't use this notation but why would people use it?

Comment: So that you can append to the list without worrying about whether or not there was a comma on the previous line.

Comment: @WaleedKhan also if you add later lines you don't need to edit the previous line to add a trailing comma, thus keeping the revision history a little tidier

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trailing commas in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)

Comment: a) it's not JSON, because in JSON this syntax is invalid. b) It's valid in pure JS based on ES >= 5; c) both the title and the first sentence here is invalid.

Comment: Please remove "JSON" from the post and title, and I may remove my downvote.  This post has absolutely nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: A key/value pair (`key: value`) is not called a "value assignment", please get your terminology straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried this notation in Chrome and it is valid.

Simply because it works in Chrome doesn't mean it's valid. It is valid because [the spec says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) :-)

> I wouldn't use this notation but why would people use it?

To make copy&pasting easier. You can just append new properties without <s>caring</s> additional work. It's a bad practice in program code because older browsers (notably IE) and the [ES3 spec disallow them](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5), but in a config file (i.e. in a known environment) it makes life easier.

Comment: Trailing commas have always been valid. The ES3 spec did not disallow them, according to the ES5 spec at http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/: "11.1.4: Edition 5 clarifies the fact that a trailing comma at the end of an ArrayInitialiser does not add to the length of the array. This is not a semantic change from Edition 3 but some implementations may have previously misinterpreted this."

Comment: @Glen: This question is about object initialisers, not about arrays :-)

Comment: oops, you're right, but this one looks like the right one, and it seems to say that a trailing comma is optional: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

Comment: You should mention the advantages for diffing.