# Conditional regex with literal at the end, only match if some part of the conditional matches as well

Tags: php, regex

Here's my test code:

```
$strings=array(
'Low Minimum',
'Low 10 Piece Minimum',
'10 piece minimum',
'20 piece minimum',
'low 6 piece minimum',
'100 piece minimum',
'This item is offered with a 1000 piece minimum',
'Place your order now. This item has a 75 piece minimum',
'Place your order now. This item has a low 75 piece minimum',
);

foreach($strings as $string)
  {
     echo preg_replace('/(low)? ?(\b[0-9]{0,3}\b) (piece minimum)/i',' Low Minumum',$string);
     echo '<br>';
  }
```

Here's the output:

```
Low Minimum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
This item is offered with a 1000 Low Minumum
Place your order now. This item has a Low Minumum
Place your order now. This item has a Low Minumum
```

Here is my desired output:

```
Low Minimum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
Low Minumum
This item is offered with a 1000 piece minimum
Place your order now. This item has a Low Minumum
Place your order now. This item has a Low Minumum
```

The one that messes me up is the 4 digit number. 
So, "piece minimum" should only match if some part of what's before it also matched.
How do I write this?

Comment: For one thing remove the comma in your last array entry `'Place your order now. This item has a low 75 piece minimum',`

Comment: @Fred-ii- having a comma after last specified array item is technically valid syntax in PHP. Though whether it is good coding practice is a different question altogether.

Comment: @JosephSilber From what I've seen so many times before, the last entry shouldn't contain a comma, or are there exceptions to the rule?

Comment: Not only is it valid, but recommended. That way, when you subsequently add more lines, your commits won't affect that line.

Comment: @Fred-ii- All entries should have a trailing comma.

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks for the info, I will definitely remember that. However, I don't why others with high rep points say that in the first place. If I had a nickel for everytime it's been said, I'd be on a Yacht somewhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Would you let me join you? :P

Comment: @JosephSilber The more the merrier ;-) cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it's important to know that in some languages you are correct. In PHP, I do it because it is convenient when I am ready to add to the array.

Comment: Back in the day, JavaScript didn't support trailing commas. [All modern browsers now support trailing commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript#answer-7246662) (besides for..... wait for it....... IE8. Bet you didn't see that one coming).

Comment: @TecBrat You're right. I think we should probably get rid of all these comments and stick to the matter at hand, good idea? Or keep them as a learning curve?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I've heard of comments being moved to wiki. Maybe these could be.

Comment: @TecBrat May as well just leave well enough alone then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you desired output, you need to change a small mistake.

Instead of..

```
[0-9]{0,3}
```

It should be..

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```

Comment: I get the same output.

Comment: I verified this works!
Edit: That said, I tested it in a regex editor

Comment: Works for me on both test sites.