# Use PHP to correctly write multiline javascript code based on set variables?

Tags: javascript, php

My Code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicky_custom = clicky_custom || {};
  clicky_custom.visitor = {
    username: 'bobjones',
    email: 'bob@jones.com'
  };
  clicky_custom.visitor_keys_cookie = ['username', 'email'];
</script>
```

You know how if you are adding another line, you need to put a comma on all the lines except for the last one? For example, the comma which appears under bob. How do I only add a comma if it is not the last line?

Comment: If you're using PHP to create Javascript literals, you should use `json_encode()` rather than trying to write it yourself.

Comment: If generating a comma-separated list in a loop I would normally just add a comma on every iteration and then after the loop take a substring of the result minus the last character. But if the language can do it for you (e.g., with `json_encode()`) take that option as a first preference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for objects, in ES5, you can leave a trailing comma. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7246662/2280630) for more information.

As for your question, it really depends on how the information is coming to you. One thing you could do is [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) an array with a comma separator. However, your best bet would be to encode your PHP arrays as JSON objects using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), which will work fine as Javascript objects. That function will output a string that you could drop directly into your script.

Comment: _"First of all, for objects, in ES5, you can leave a trailing comma."_ - Though there are still plenty of IE8 users out there, so...

Comment: You're right, of course! Just thought it was relevant information.