# Expression Engine Autocomplete with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [

    {model_ref}
    ];
  $( "#model" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
  });
  });
 });
```

How can I get this to populate the input from expression engine entries?

Answer (score 1):

@JamesNZ has it and this worked for me.

To avoid any weirdness with the way arrays work in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript), I added an extra empty value to the end of the returned array, like this.

```
<script>
    var availableTags = [
        {exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
        "{title}",
        {/exp:channel:entries}
       "" //extra empty value here.
    ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're after with the [expressionengine channel entries](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html) tag.

```
<script>
var availableTags = [
    {exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
    "{title}",
    {/exp:channel:entries}
];
</script>
```

This will produce some javascript like:

```
<script>
var availableTags = [
    "First value",
    "Second value",
    "Third value",
    ... etc ...
];
</script>
```

The only thing is this code will have to be in a template (not a standalone JS file).