# Does the object javascript syntax right or wrong ?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Here it is:

```
var obj = {
    'city': 'ny',
}
```

I write a comma in the end after `ny`

but this could run in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE6/7

So does this kind of syntax is right or wrong or recommended?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

> there should be not comma,if you have only one key and value.
>
> ```
> If you are separating the Key & Value Pairs with comma then it is called as Object Literals.
> ```

```
var obj = {
    'city': 'ny'
}
```