# Array w/ all elements (except the first) undefined returns wrong length

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = ["string", , ]
console.log(arr.length)
```

Why is the length of arr 2 and not 3?

Comment: Trailing commas in array and object literals are ignored, they use to be syntax errors back in the day.

Comment: @Musa Does IE finally permit them? I haven't really worked with it since IE9, when it was still a syntax error.

Comment: @Musa should you put your comment as an answer? It seems to answer the question correctly.

Comment: They works in IE11, don't know in which version it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of array literals introduced back in ES3.

You can put leading or trilling commas as "empty" elements

so `[,,,,1,2,3,,]` would yield an array of length 7, with first 4 and the last elements empty.

If you put this expression into the console in Firefox 34.0.5 it would say

`Array [ <4 empty slots>, 1, 2, 3, <1 empty slot> ]`

Sources:

[Are trailing commas in arrays and objects part of the spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

section 11.1.4