# javascript object array with multiple options

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array with multiple object with multiple options each in Javascript.

But I seem to be going in the wrong direction. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var group = {[
    'object1'[
        'option1' : 'data1.1',
        'option2' : 'data1.2',
        'option3' : 'data1.3',
    ],
    'object2'[
        'option1' : 'data2.1',
        'option2' : 'data2.2',
        'option3' : 'data2.3',
    ],
    'object3'[
        'option1' : 'data3.1',
        'option2' : 'data3.2',
        'option3' : 'data3.3',
    ],
]};
```

Comment: Did you try `'object1': {` (etc)?

Comment: Does putting a coma after the last element of an array cause a problem ? I can't see anything else wrong

Comment: You're creating an object with multiple arrays and you'll need `:` between your `objectX` and the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to always use `name : value` pairs.
Instead of `[]` use `{}` to define a map (`[]` is for arrays). Edit: I've overseen that before.

```
var group = {
    'object1': {
        'option1' : 'data1.1',
        'option2' : 'data1.2',
        'option3' : 'data1.3'
    },
    'object2': {
        'option1' : 'data2.1',
        'option2' : 'data2.2',
        'option3' : 'data2.3'
    },
    'object3': {
        'option1' : 'data3.1',
        'option2' : 'data3.2',
        'option3' : 'data3.3'
    }
};
```

Remove the last comma in each list - IE<=8 (I think) can't handle it.
See [Are trailing commas in arrays and objects part of the spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This object contains 3 nested object.

```
var group = {
    'object1': {
        'option1': 'data1.1',
        'option2': 'data1.2',
        'option3': 'data1.3'
    },
    'object2': {
        'option1': 'data2.1',
        'option2': 'data2.2',
        'option3': 'data2.3'
    },
    'object3': {
        'option1': 'data3.1',
        'option2': 'data3.2',
        'option3': 'data3.3'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax problems. The code should be:

```
var group = [
    {
        option1: 'data1.1',
        option2: 'data1.2',
        option3: 'data1.3',
    },
    {
        option1: 'data2.1',
        option2: 'data2.2',
        option3: 'data2.3',
    },
    {
        option1: 'data3.1',
        option2: 'data3.2',
        option3: 'data3.3',
    }
];
```

Comment: I need this array of objects to have a name for each object to loop through it and identify the correct option according to the specified object. Is it possible to have a name for each object?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error:

```
var group = [
    {
        option1: 'data1.1',
        option2: 'data1.2',
        option3: 'data1.3'
    },
    {
        option1: 'data2.1',
        option2: 'data2.2',
        option3: 'data2.3'
    },
    {
        option1: 'data3.1',
        option2: 'data3.2',
        option3: 'data3.3'
    }
];
```

please read about creating [Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) and [Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) in javascript

Answer (score 0):

No need to give multiple array inside.
To access `data1.1` use `group[0].option1`

```
var group = [
 {
    'option1' : 'data1.1',
    'option2' : 'data1.2',
    'option3' : 'data1.3',
 },
 {
    'option1' : 'data2.1',
    'option2' : 'data2.2',
    'option3' : 'data2.3',
},
{
    'option1' : 'data3.1',
    'option2' : 'data3.2',
    'option3' : 'data3.3',
},
];
```