# JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, kendo-ui

I have the below ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window = $("#window");
    viewModel.validator = $("#Details").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator")({
        rules: {
            checkPersonContactInfo: function (input) {
                if (intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.Email") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.CellPhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.HomePhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.WorkPhone") == '') {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        },
    });
    if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
        window.kendoWindow({
            width: "600px",
            title: "Valdiation errors",
            visible: false
        });
    };
});
```

Whenever I debug it blows off and gives me error saying "0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected". I checked multiple times if I am missing any parenthesis but I cannot see anything.

Comment: How do we reproduce this error ?

Comment: @RayonDabre this is happening on page load. I think i might be missing some parenthesis or semicolon.

Comment: Sounds like you've passed some other type of argument (or not argument at all) instead of a function. Also, in your code `data('kendoValidator')` must return a function. Does it? If it returns an object instead, you've missed the dot and the method name, since an argumentlist follows: `... = $("#Details").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator")({rules: {...})`. Notice two sequential `()`s here.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found more wrong syntax, you have an unneeded comma & semi-colon:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window = $("#window");
    viewModel.validator = $("#Details").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator")({
        rules: {
            checkPersonContactInfo: function (input) {
                if (intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.Email") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.CellPhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.HomePhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.WorkPhone") == '') {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        } // here there was a comma which was not needed.
    });
    if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
        window.kendoWindow({
            width: "600px",
            title: "Valdiation errors",
            visible: false
        });
    } //here you had also a trailing ; which I removed
});
```

Comment: yes, trailing comma in a javascript object will cause syntax error

Comment: It will never give you syntax error. Its just not needed there.

Comment: If you write it in a good IDE with linter it will give you a syntax error.

Comment: We can never call them **syntax errors**, this is just a warning which need to ne avoided, but this is not the cause in this case..

Comment: Just saying, a trailing comma will trigger a __parsing time__ syntax error, and only in older IEs.

Comment: [They are part of the spec since ES5 and legal in array definitions since ES3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/trailing-commas-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The trailing comma could be the issue:

```
 },
```

Comment: Depends on how you run it. I would expect a browser to not have an issue with is, but I don't know how you ran this code.

Comment: I faced in IE. ::(( Give it a try, you never know

Comment: I gave this a try and I am stinng getting the same error @MichaelD

Comment: One more thing that Lint shows that could be relevant: The ; on the line before the last. This one is not needed. Can you try it?

Comment: I tried that @MichaelD that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

like mentioned before the trailing comma is the problem in your code.
A trailing comma in JavaScript object literals is valid since the ECMAScript 5 specification and so it is valid in the most modern browser. Nevertheless there are problems with IE and in older browser you get syntax errors.

I just optimized it with the help of WebStorm and this is the output of WebStorm :-) (There was also an unnecessary semicolon in your code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window = $("#window");
    var viewModel = {};
    viewModel.validator = $("#Details").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator")({
        rules: {
            checkPersonContactInfo: function (input) {
                return !(intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.Email") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.CellPhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.HomePhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.WorkPhone") == '');
            }
        }
    });
    if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
        window.kendoWindow({
            width: "600px",
            title: "Valdiation errors",
            visible: false
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to do something like this:

```
viewModel.validator = $("#Details").kendoValidator({//this is the change you need
        rules: {
            checkPersonContactInfo: function (input) {
                if (intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.Email") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.CellPhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.HomePhone") == '' && intakeView.viewModel.get("personDetails.WorkPhone") == '') {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        },
    });
```

**MORE:** [see this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/custom-validation)

Comment: according to the article you shared we should define validator like this: var validator = $("#Details").data("kendoValidator");

Comment: This part is to add rules to your validator. on your call(save/update) it should trigger the defined validation rules as in the given link he is doing on `save`.