# Randomly set background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I want to randomly set a background-image on an element.

Here is what I am trying:

```
<div id="headImg"></div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var images = ['bg.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg', 'bg5.jpg', 'bg6.jpg', 'bg7.jpg', 'bg8.jpg'];

    $('#headImg').css( 'background-image', 'url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')' );

  });

</script>
```

I am obviously doing something wrong since I cant get it to work.

This is also WordPress. So if I set and inline background image like this it works:

```
 style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/bg.jpg);"
```

But I want to use jQuery to randomly set the background image inline. Is this even possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Is this even possible* — Did it work when you tried it? You have a trailing comma in your `images` array declaration.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: No, not without a change or 2.

Comment: @agon024: What does `get_template_directory_uri();` return?

Comment: @JonnyHenly, The trailing comma should not matter. It is still valid JS.

Comment: @Jinjubei does it not affect the length of the array?

Comment: Show us the final page source in browser (the part when you're changing the image).

Comment: IE at the very least will throw an error from that trailing comma and fail to run your code.

Comment: Ok. Wow! all of this for a trailing slash that makes no difference :). I have updated the code :).

Comment: @JefréN. get_template_directory_uri(); returns the my custom theme directory.

Comment: @agon024 Returns what exactly? If there are some special characters, it may cause the problem.

Comment: This works, as it is (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqWZyJ with made up path). What is going wrong exactly? Do you have a javascript error? You can debug this very easily, just inspect the element that should have a background and see what its background is. If it *doesn't* have one, then you have a javascript syntax error. Stick an alert or a console.log() in your .ready() method to make sure it's being run. Etc. What you have is correct though, so we'll need more information.

Comment: @JonnyHenly, from my testing it ignores the trailing comma because there is not data for it to put in at the end.

Comment: @Jinjubei Most browsers ignore a *single* trailing comma, Internet Explorer on the other hand increases the length of the array. — [Trailing commas in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11306770/1241334)

Comment: @JonnyHenly, Ahhh the infamous IE causes an issue. Honestly so used to writing for a controlled environment these days I forget about that sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this code fails is because `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` can **only** be evaluated when the page is requested from the server. (PHP is a [server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) language.)

Hence, this line accomplishes nothing when dynamically generated with jQuery:

```
 $('#headImg').css( 'background-image', 'url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')' );
```

If, however, you replaced `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` with the return value of `get_template_directory_uri();`, to form this:

```
$('#headImg').css( 'background-image', 'url((return value here)/assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')' );
```

Your code would run properly.

**Edit:**

As you can see from the comments below my post, people said--rightly so--that in certain cases, his code *would've* worked.

However, code that embeds php only works if the code is in the file being requested. (ie. It is inline code, rather than external code from different pages.) However, in this case, the jQuery was **not** in the same file ... That is why he had to remove the offending php tag.

**In recap:**

This solution was necessary because the javascript was not in the requested .php file. Hence, the PHP tags were not evaluated. (PHP tags mean nothing in javascript files.)

If, however, the javascript would have been in the requested PHP file, it would've worked fine.

Comment: Who tells you this isn't running on a server?

Comment: @Jojo01: Huh? Could you please explain your question? Did you read my answer?

Comment: The php will echo in the location of the directory before the page is loaded, but as you said it needs to be on a server to work. Hence your answer implies that this page is not being requested from a server. But how do you know that?

Comment: @Jojo01: When the jQuery changes the background image for `#headImg`, the *page is no longer on the server.* Hence, the code between the tags, **will not run.** It will, however, be invalid CSS.

Comment: If we assume that the code provided by the author of the question is in some _.php_ file, then the PHP code will be processed and will return the directory path. So, in browser, there won't be any `<?php ...`.

Comment: Um. This is what I was thinking also. So after doing what you said, it does work. I replace it with the return value and it randomly changes on page refresh. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: I have myself echoed javascript inside javascript with php and it has worked.

Comment: @Jojo01 then tell my why this isn't working if you know how to do it. Cause i feel he is right.

Comment: Can you create another empty .php with this code? `<html><script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#v").html(<?php echo '"'.get_template_directory_uri();.'"' ?>); });</script><body><h1 id="v">No value</h1></body></html>`

Comment: Guys, I just explained why it had to be done this way. Sorry, for any confusion.

Comment: I edited the comment with the code, does the text of the h1 change to what get_template_directory_uri(); returns?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 7 images you can maybe just do it like this:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
$('#headImg').css( 'background-image', 'url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/bg' + rand + '.jpg)' );
```

Basically you can just create a random number between 1 and 7, then add that number to bg and .jpg e.g bg5.jpg

Comment: Why the downvote? This would work, although you'd need to change the limit for the random number if you add or remove images. This also simplifies things a lot.

Comment: It doesn't simplify anything at all, it enforces a naming convention on the images and doesn't even work since there is no bg1.jpg and has a hard-coded range.