# Trailing comma in JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to follow the JS code style defined by [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--signature-invocation-indentation).

The rule on trailing commas for function call arguments states:

> 7.15 Functions with multiline signatures, or invocations, should be indented just like every other multiline list in this guide: with each item on a line by itself, with a trailing comma on the last item.

But when I do the following:

```
/* THREE.js constructor for PerspectiveCamera */
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000,
);
```

Google Chrome complains with the following error:

> app.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

When I remove the trailing comma everything works fine. This code works fine in Firefox and I am fairly sure it worked a week ago from today (11.04.2017) in Chrome as well - because I haven't changed my code since than and I was presenting the app I'm working on to my colleague.

Note that trailing comma in arrays still works fine:

```
testArray = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
];
```

Can someone explain this behavior or point me to where I can look for more information?

Using Google Chrome (Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It is legal syntax and is often used in large code bases where miltuple people might be adding parameters to functions etc. But it's also a setting in most LINTers, since it does have effects on the length property of functions and arrays, so it can create bugs. Also, IE doesn't like them. Also ahve a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246618/are-trailing-commas-in-arrays-and-objects-part-of-the-spec

Comment: @Shilly - Chrome and FF don't like trailing commas in function arguments either.

Comment: Depends on the version and settings used. Imho trailing commas should be avoided. Hence I don't like the airbnb style. But that's personaly opinion.

Comment: Relevant specification references: [_Arguments_](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Arguments), [ArgumentListEvaluation](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation). MDN documentation: [Trailing commas](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#function_calls), also contains a [compatibility table](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#browser_compatibility). Original proposal: [Proposal to allow trailing commas in function parameter lists](//github.com/tc39/proposal-trailing-function-commas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My team just ran into this issue with a user who has **Chrome 55.0.2883.87**.
This version of Chrome also reports unexpected token at ')' as reported above.

The trailing commas DO seem to be TOLERATED by **Chrome 60.0.3112.113**.
No error.

So we can deduce that Google is moving towards support for the trailing comma.